# How to sort an xml file by attribute value in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to sort an xml file by the attribute value "class" of the  element "entity". In output I want to keep the same structure of my input xml,
Here a part of my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
<entity class="entityZ" metadata-complete="false">
<table name="F_ENTITYZ">
<unique-constraint>
<column-name>column1</column-name>
</unique-constraint>
<unique-constraint>
<column-name>column2</column-name>
</unique-constraint>
</table>
<sequence-generator name="SEQUENCEZ_" sequence-name="F_SEQUENCEZ_" allocation-size="1" initial-value="1"/>
<attributes>
</attributes>
</entity>
<entity class="entityA" metadata-complete="false">
<table name="F_ENTITYA">
<unique-constraint>
<column-name>column1</column-name>
</unique-constraint>
</table>
<sequence-generator name="SEQUENCEA_" sequence-name="F_SEQUENCEA_" allocation-size="1" initial-value="1"/>
<attributes>
</attributes>
<post-persist method-name="traceHistory"/>
<post-update method-name="traceHistory"/>
</entity>
<entity class="entityB" metadata-complete="false">
<table name="F_ENTITYB">
<unique-constraint>
<column-name>column1</column-name>
</unique-constraint>
</table>
<sequence-generator name="SEQUENCEB_" sequence-name="F_SEQUENCEB_" allocation-size="1" initial-value="1"/>
<attributes>
</attributes>
</entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Waiting for your help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xslt you can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">

        <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
            <xsl:sort select="@class" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>

    </entity-mappings>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I copied this code into sort.xsl file and added this code to my xml "<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sort.xsl"?>" 
 but it does not work for me.

Comment: It fails to compile or...?

Comment: No, it doesn't fail but it just displays the column-name without sorting them; I need to sort the content and copy all of it (with all the elements name and attributes)

Comment: Note that if you are using the `xml-stylesheet` directive, then this suggests you are using the browser to do the transformation of the XML. When you use `xml-stylesheet` in this way, browsers generally expect HTML to be output, so you probably wouldn't see the output rendered correctly if you were outputing XML.

Comment: See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwT for an example of this answer doing the sorting as expected though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works perfectly :)